# Onchange event in select should change others inputs field value?

Tags: reactjs

As a Begineer in a react,here what i want to do is when i select options from the react-select option the i want to dispaly that selected options label in the text input  down above on both field but got problem with here onchanges event How to change value in text field from the select options along with selected value?

**Code**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const initialValues = [{ number: "", options: "" }];
const countries = [
  { id: 1, name: USA },
  { id: 2, name: Russia },
  { id: 3, name: UK },
];
const Newrow = (props) => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");
  const [options, setoption] = useState([]);
  const [options1, setoption1] = useState("");
  const addRow = () => {
    let _row = {
      number: "",
      options: "",
    };
    props.setData(_row);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="number"
        value={number}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setNumber(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        className="input"
        value={options}
        onChange={options1}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        className="input"
        value={options}
        onChange={options1}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default function App(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const addRow = (row) => {
    setData([...data, row]);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        options={countries}
        value={{
          label: name,
          value: id,
        }}
        onChange={(e) => {
          const res = {
            id: e.value,
            name: e.label,
          };
          console.log(res);
          setoption1(res);
        }}
      ></Select>

      {[...data, ...initialValues].map((row, idx) => {
        return (
          <Newrow
            setData={addRow}
            data={row}
            key={idx}
            delrow={idx}
            options1={options1}
          />
        );
      })}
      <button
        type="submit"
        onClick={() => addRow({ number: "", options: "" })}
        className="btn btn-success"
      >
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be passing in `options1` (a string) into the `onChange` handler of your text inputs. The `onChange` handler should only take a function, that will be triggered when those inputs change.

You can discard the `onChange={options1}` property and change the value property to `value={options1}`.

Change this:

```
<input type="text"
  className="input"
  value={options}
  onChange={options1}
/>
```

to this:

```
<input type="text"
  className="input"
  value={options1}
/>
```